# Can't import StrBuf?

Tags: import, rust

I can't import `StrBuf`.

Here's an example program that demonstrates my problem:

```
use std::strbuf::StrBuf;
fn main() {}
```

*rustc test.rs* gives me the following error:

```
test.rs:1:5: 1:16 error: unresolved import: there is no `strbuf` in `std`
test.rs:1 use std::strbuf;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.rs:1:5: 1:16 error: failed to resolve import `std::strbuf`
test.rs:1 use std::strbuf;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

What's going on?

(I'm using version 0.10, at least according to `rustc --version`.)

Comment: are you uing 0.10? or maybe some older version of nightly?

Comment: `rustc --version` says 0.10.

Comment: there is no StrBuf in 0.10, it was added after that

Comment: Thanks! I'll find another solution.

Comment: you just use ~str in 0.10

Comment: Note that `StrBuf` has since been renamed to [`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Rust as of version `0.10` didn't have StrBuf. You might want to update to latest nightly to use `StrBuf`.

Otherwise use `~str`. It should have most methods of `StrBuf`.